# How to reverse the buttons' click order on one mouse in a dual mice setup?

Tags: windows-vista, mouse-click

I use two mice, one on each side of the keyboard.

I would like to swap the effect of the mice buttons so each is mirrored. Changing the click effect in the options does it for both mice at the same time.

I am **not** looking for two simultaneous pointers, but simply a way for each mouse to work in either native left or right button setup respectively.

OS: Windows Vista